# Find characteristic polynomial

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ complex matrices such that $$AB-BA=aI+A,$$ where $a \in \mathbb{C}.$ Find the characteristic polynomial of $A$.
If $A$ happens to be a Jordan block, this would be easy:

Write $A=cI+N$ with $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and $N$ nilpotent. Then $$(cI+N)B-B(cI+N)=(a+c)I+N,$$
that is, $$NB-BN=(a+c)I+N.$$
Take trace of both sides to get $c=-a$. So the characteristic polynomial would be $(x+a)^n$.
So I guess for a general $A$, the answer is the same?

Comment: Note that if $A=XJX^{-1}$, then $X^{-1}(AB-BA)X=X^{-1}(XJX^{-1}B-BXJX^{-1})X=J\tilde{B}-\tilde{B}J$ and $X^{-1}(aI+A)X=aI+J$, thus transforming the problem to the case where $A$ is the matrix from the Jordan form. However, $J$ is generally a direct sum of elementary Jordan blocks.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel But what if $\tilde{B}$ cannot be decomposed into blocks that match the sizes of the blocks of $J$?

Comment: You might still work with $\tilde{B}$ partitioned according to the dimensions of the small Jordan blocks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [If A and (AB-BA) commute, show that AB-BA is nilpotent](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227984/if-a-and-ab-ba-commute-show-that-ab-ba-is-nilpotent)