# If nilpotent matrix $A$ and $AB−BA$ commute, show that $AB$ is nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n×n$ complex matrices.
>
> If $A$ is a nilpotent matrix, and $A$ commute with $AB−BA$, show that $AB$ is nilpotent.

Equivalently, the question can be expressed as following description.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n×n$ complex matrices.
>
> Define the linear transformation $T$ as $T(B)=AB-BA$.
>
> If $A$ is a nilpotent matrix, and $T^2(B)=0$ , show that $AB$ is nilpotent.

I've known that $AB-BA$ is nilpotent.

Furtherly, if $A^m=0$ , by considering $T^n(B)=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^iA^{n-i}BA^i$ , I found that $A^kBA^l=0$ when $k+l\geqslant m$.

But I don't know how to continue, thanks for any help.

Comment: Compare also with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227984/if-a-and-ab-ba-commute-show-that-ab-ba-is-nilpotent?rq=1).

Comment: This is actually the main theorem of an [article by Kaplansky](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82031256.pdf). The statement is even generalized there.

Comment: @Helmut: The link is dead. What article of Kaplansky's is it? Maybe "Jacobson's Lemma Revisited" (J. Algebra 62, 473-476 (1980)), cf. https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0425.16020 ?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, that is the article. By the way, the link is active again:-)