# Show that $AB$ is nilpotent

Tags: matrices, nilpotence

> Let $A,B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices. If $A^2B-2ABA+BA^2=0$ and $A$ is nilpotent, that is, there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $A^k=0$. Show that $AB$ is nilpotent.

If $k=2$, it is OK. Since $(AB)^2=ABAB=\frac{1}{2}(A^2B+BA^2)B=0$. But if $k\geq 3$, what

Comment: The given it's $[A,[A,B]]=0.$

Comment: It is a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177989/if-nilpotent-matrix-a-and-ab%E2%88%92ba-commute-show-that-ab-is-nilpotent?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Given $A$ is nilpotent, means there exists a real k such that $A^m=0$ for all $m\ge k$ and $A^p\ne0$ for all $p\lt k$. 
So you have initial equation $A^2B-2ABA+BA^2=0$. 
Now left multiply the equation both sides by $A^{k-2}$.
You get : $0+2A^{k-1}BA+A^{k-2}BA^2=0$.
Now,take $A^{k-2}$ common. Since it is non zero, the other part has to be zero.
So $2ABA+BA^2=0$. Now you right Multiply both sides by $A^{k-2}$. Now you get $2ABA^{k-1}=0$. Following similar argument,you conclude $AB=0$. So obviously,$AB$ is nilpotent as $(AB)^k=0$ for any $k\ge1$

Comment: The determinant of $A^{k-2}$ is zero, $A$ being nilpotent.

Comment: Sorry, a mistake

Comment: @Tojrah "since it is non zero, the other part has to be zero" - why is this true?

Comment: The matrix product $XY$ can be zero with *both* matrices being nonzero.

Comment: May be there is some kind of assumption for the question