# Application of Lie algebra on linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is nilpotent and $B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. If $AB-BA$ and $A$ commute, prove that $AB$ is nilpotent.

If you can prove that the Lie algebra generated by $A$ and $B$ is solvable, the problem will be finished by Lie theroem. But I can't prove it.

Comment: See the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177989/if-nilpotent-matrix-a-and-ab%e2%88%92ba-commute-show-that-ab-is-nilpotent?noredirect=1&lq=1) here.

Comment: @DietrichBurde it is a subalgebra of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, so it is indeed finite dimensional.

Comment: The duplicate links to a paper by Kaplanski. The proof there seems to be the best. I don't see how to use Lie's theorem with a shorter proof.