# If we have $A_{n \times n}$ and $AX-XA=A$, how do we show that $\det(A)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, determinant

**If we have $A_{n \times n}$ and $AX-XA=A$, how do we show that $\det(A)=0$?**

I've tried taking the trace on both sides to get

$$tr(AX)-tr(XA)=tr(A)$$
$$tr(AX)-tr(AX)=tr(A)$$
$$0=tr(A)$$

However, that doesn't necessarily show that $\det(A)=0$

Comment: I'm not sure whether to mark this as a duplicate.  Nilpotent matrices necessarily have determinant 0.  $A$ commutes with its commutator, hence is nilpotent -- this is known as Jacobson's Lemma.    See e.g. here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227984/if-a-and-ab-ba-commute-show-that-ab-ba-is-nilpotent

Comment: The answers posted so far seem to assume---very reasonably, given the context---that the matrices have entries in a field of characteristic $0$. In characteristic $p$, (1) if $p | n$ then the $n \times n$ identity matrix has trace $0$ (and so there is not contradiction in Andreas' and River's answers), and (2) it's possible for all of $\lambda, \lambda + 1, \lambda + 2, \ldots$ to be eigenvalues of a matrix, since there are only $p$ distinct numbers in that list. I'm curious whether the original statement is even true in positive characteristic.

Comment: In fact it is not true; in characteristic $2$, the matrices $A = \pmatrix{1&1\\\cdot&1}$, $X = \pmatrix{\cdot&1\\1&1}$ satisfy $A X - X A = A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\det A \ne 0$.

Left-multiplying $A^{-1}$ on both sides of $AX - XA = A$, we have
$X - A^{-1}XA = I$.

Right-multiplying $A^{-1}$ on both sides of $AX - XA = A$, we have
$AXA^{-1} - X = I$.

Add them up to get $AXA^{-1} - A^{-1}XA = 2I$.

Note that $\mathrm{Tr}(AXA^{-1}) - \mathrm{Tr}(A^{-1}XA) = \mathrm{Tr}(X) - \mathrm{Tr}(X) = 0$,
and $\mathrm{Tr}(2I) \ne 0$.

Contradiction. (Q. E. D.)

Answer (score 7):

Rewrite the equation as  $A (X-I) = XA$.  If $A$ is nonsingular, that implies $X - I = A^{-1} X A$, i.e. $X$ is similar to $X-I$.
That says $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $X$ if and only if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $X-I$, i.e. $\lambda+1$ is an eigenvalue of $X$. But this is impossible, as it would mean $\lambda+n$ is an eigenvalue of $X$ for every integer $n$, but $X$ has only finitely many eigenvalues.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Robert Israel's answer, but without explicitly using eigenvalues: If $A$ were invertible, we could multiply the given equation on the right by $A^{-1}$ to get $AXA^{-1}-X=I$.  Taking the trace of both sides and remembering that $AXA^{-1}$ has the same trace as $X$ (and that trace is linear), we get that the trace of the identity matrix is $0$, a contradiction.

[Pedantic technicality: That final "contradiction" assumes that you don't allow $0\times0$ matrices. If you do allow them, the result is false, as the hypothesis holds when both $A$ and $X$ are the empty matrix, but the determinant of the empty matrix is $1$.]

Comment: (+1) Your solution is better.