# Simultaneous triangularization for AB-BA

Tags: triangularization

Is it true in general that if $A, B \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $AB-BA=P(A)$ where $P \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, then $A$ and $B$ are simultanously triangularzible? I know that if $AB-BA=A^k$ for a positive integer $k$ then it is true ($Ker(A)$ is $B$-invariant and so the triangularization builds recursively). But is it true for any polynomial $P$?

Comment: And by assumption $A$ and $AB-BA$ commute, so the claim follows from [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227984/if-a-and-ab-ba-commute-show-that-ab-ba-is-nilpotent).

Comment: Why does it follow that if $AB-BA$ is nilpotent then $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously triangularizble?

Comment: See your [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4654136/ab-ba-nilpotent-implies-simultaneous-triangularization), which is still visible. Did you find it in the literature? I just had a look and only find [this result](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/0024379580902402?token=460B8B44C8CEFA8E48C2CDDE079EC7052EAEFB6589BAFAAB160598309FC36417654A028A54BC9F17664BF1AD2B8CFFF4&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20230326115020), using McCoy.

Comment: I came up with my old question because I wanted to solve the problem that I posted above.  I still don't know if $AB-BA$ nilpotent implies ST.

Comment: The authors says yes, if $C=AB-BA$ satisfies $C^2=0$, but otherwise it seems to be not true in general (so we need to check again).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 2-step solution. I hope that the 1st step can be simplified, but I also hope that after my edits it is clear :)

1. We can reduce to the case when $A$ is nilpotent.

Indeed, if $A$ is general and $Q(x)=\prod_{i=1}^k(x-\lambda_i)^{n_i}$ is its characteristic polynomial ($k$ is the number of roots of $Q$), we have the $A$-invariant decomposition
$$\mathbb C^n =\bigoplus_{i=1}^k V_i \quad\text{where}\quad V_i:=\ker(A-\lambda_i)^{n_i}\qquad(1)$$
Moreover we can find polynomials $Q_i$ such that $Q_i(A)$ is the projector to $V_i$ in this direct sum (e.g. by decomposing $1/Q(x)$ to partial fractions and then multiplying the terms by $Q(x)$).

Let us prove that $[Q_i(A), B]=0$ for all $i=1,\dots,k$.
Since $A$ commutes with $[A,B]=AB-BA=P(A)$, we have $[Q_i(A), B]=Q_i'(A)P(A)$, and thus $[Q_i(A), B]$ commutes with $A$ and therefore also with $Q_i(A)$. Since $Q_i(A)^2=Q_i(A)$ (a projector), we get
$$[Q_i(A),B]=[Q_i(A)^2,B]=$$
$$=Q_i(A)\,[Q_i(A),B]+[Q_i(A),B]\,Q_i(A)= 2[Q_i(A),B]\,Q_i(A).\quad(2)$$
Since on $V_j$ we have either $Q_i(A)=0$ (if $i\neq j$) or $Q_i(A)=1$ (if $i=j$), we get from $(2)$ that on $V_j$ either $[Q_i(A),B]=0$ or $[Q_i(A),B]=2[Q_i(A),B]$, so (in both cases) $[Q_i(A),B]=0$ on $V_j$, hence (since $j$ was arbitrary) $[Q_i(A),B]=0$ on the entire space $\mathbb C^n$.

To conclude the 1st part: $[Q_i(A),B]=0$ implies that the decomposition $(1)$
is  $B$-invariant. We can thus restrict ourselves to the subspaces $V_i=\ker(A-\lambda_i)^{n_i}\subset\mathbb C^n$, and if we replace $A$ by $A-\lambda_i$, we make it nilpotent there.

2. Supposing that $A$ is nilpotent.

Since $\operatorname{Tr} (AB-BA)=0$ and also $\operatorname{Tr}A^k=0$ for all $k>0$, we must have $P(0)=0$, i.e. $AB-BA = H(A)A$ for some polynomial $H$. Hence $\ker A$ is $B$-invariant, and this implies (by induction) that a simultaneous triangularization exists.

Comment: Can you explain why $[Qi(A),B]=0$ implies that the decomposition (1) is B-invariant?
Is $ker(Q_i(A))$ $=$ $V_i$?

Comment: The way I meant it, the image of $Q_i(A)$ was $V_i$ and its kernel was the sum of $V_j$'s, $j\neq i$. But you can replace $Q_i(A)$ with $1-Q_i(A)$ ($[1-Q_i(A), B]=0$ certainly) and the kernel is now $V_i$.