# Characterisation of normal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to prove the following?

**Lemma.** Let $C=[A,A^{\star}]$. $A$ is normal iff $[A,C]=0$.

One direction is trivial. The other direction reduces to showing that $A^2 A^\star+A^\star A^2=0$ implies that $A$ is normal, but I don't see why that holds.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $[A,C]=AC-CA=A(AA^*-A^*A)-(AA^*-A^*A)A=A^2A^*-2AA^*A+A^*A^2=0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $[A,C]=0$. As $C$ is Hermitian, it is normal and possesses a complete eigensystem. If $(\lambda,x)$ is an eigenpair of $C$, then $C(Ax) = ACx = \lambda Ax$. In other words, every eigenspace of $C$ is an invariant subspace of $A$.

Pick any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $C$ and denote the associated eigenspace by $V$. Since eigenspaces of $C$ (being a normal matrix) are orthogonal to each other *and* they are invariant subspaces of $A$, the restriction of $C$ on $V$ is still the commutator of $A$ and $A^\ast$ restricted on $V$. But every commutator is traceless. Therefore $\lambda$ must be zero. Hence all eigenvalues of $C$ are zero and $C=0$.

---

**EDIT.** Ahhh, I've finally found it! Initially, I wanted to offer a one-line proof using a more general fact, but I couldn't locate the sources and ended up with the above. Now the proof can be greatly simplified.

**A one-line proof.** As $A$ commutes with $C=[A,A^\ast]$, [$C$ is nilpotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/225022/1551) (see also [q227984](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/227984/1551) and [q299640](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299640/1551)); since $C$ is also Hermitian, it must be zero and hence $A$ is normal.

Comment: $C = AA^* - A^*A$ is actually Hermitian (not skew-Hermitian) since both $AA^*$ and $A^*A$ are Hermitian (in fact, positive).

Comment: @Mike Thanks, you're right. It's now fixed.